# Combining CSV of different shapes into one CSV

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv, dataframe, concatenation

I have CSVs of different number of rows and columns. I would like to create one large CSV where all the CSV data are stacked directly on top of each other, aligned by the first column. I tried the script below with limited success; b which is an empty array does not hold the data from the previous loops.

```
from os import walk
import sys
import numpy as np

filenames= []
dirpath = []
filtered = []
original = []
f = []
b = np.empty([2, 2])



for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk("C:\\Users\\dkim1\\Python Scripts\\output"): 
     f.extend(dirnames) 

print(f) 

for names in f:  
    print(names)
    df = np.genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\dkim1\\Python Scripts\\output\\' + names + '\\replies.csv', dtype =None, delimiter = ',', skip_header=1, names=True)
    b = np.column_stack(df)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pd.concat()?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# just used a single dir for example simplicity, rather than os.walk()
root_dir = "your directory path here"
file_names = os.listdir(root_dir)

cat_list=[]
for names in file_names:  
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root_dir, names), delimiter = ',', header=None)
    cat_list.append(df)


concatted_df = pd.concat(cat_list)
```